# apt-get autoremove is messing up locale stuff after having installed the gdal-bin package from debian testing main

Tags: debian, apt, docker, locale, gdal

I am trying to update the `gdal-bin` package from Debian unstable in the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgis/postgis:15-master

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get -y update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
     apt-get -y install \
       --fix-missing \
       --no-install-recommends gdal-bin \
  && apt-get -y autoremove --purge
```

but when it comes to `apt-get autoremove`, it messes up the locales stuff (which in turns crashes the database initialization when I want to spin up a container from this image):

```
(...)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libaom0* libdav1d4* libgeos-3.9.0* libx265-192*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 134 not upgraded.
After this operation, 24.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.utf8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Here are some useful links:

- https://mastizada.com/blog/how-to-solve-locale-problem-in-linux-powered-servers/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/362903/how-do-you-set-a-locale-non-interactively-on-debian-ubuntu/689947#689947
- https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Perl_warning_Setting_locale_failed_in_Debian
- http://jaredmarkell.com/docker-and-locales/

Answer (score 1):

This warning (not error) means that `en_US.UTF-8` hasn't been configured on the system and when a perl script is executed, perl warns about it.

Try adding this to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN /sbin/locale-gen
```

It'll generate the needed files for all the locales that are listed in `/etc/locale.gen`.

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: /sbin/locale-gen: not found` on Debian based image. Also: `# ls /sbin/l* /sbin/ldconfig /sbin/logsave  /sbin/losetup`. It's apparently under: `/usr/sbin/locale-gen`

Comment: Ah yes. If you don't have `usrmerge` installed then `/sbin/` and `/usr/sbin/` are different on Debian. This will change when `bookworm` (next stable) is released.